# Dynamic pivot table SQL Server stored procedure or in Crysal Reports

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports, dynamic-pivot

I am struggling with find a solution for report from dynamic pivot table in SQL Server to Crystal Report or to merge to stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @Columns as VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(loc_id)
FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT loc_id 
    FROM request_hd 
    WHERE entry_date = '2018-06-23' 
      AND valid = '1') AS B
ORDER BY B.loc_id

DECLARE @SQL as VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT item_code,item_ref,item_des,Shelf,WH_stock,WH_stockchk_qty, ' + @Columns + '
FROM
(
  SELECT I.item_code,
  I.item_ref,
  I.item_des,
  I.unit_qty,
  L.loc_id AS LocationName, 
     (select Sum(qty) from stock where stock.item_code = I.item_code and loc_id = ''901'' ) as WH_stock,
(select isnull(sum(qty),0) from stock_chk where stock_chk.item_code = I.item_code and loc_id like ''901'') as WH_stockchk_qty,
 (CAST( (Q.shelf_desc) AS VARCHAR)+''-''+CAST( (Q.shelf_rowSCOUNT) AS VARCHAR)+CAST( (Q.shelf_rowlength) AS VARCHAR)) as Shelf
from request_tran I, request_hd L, shelf_detail P, shelf_mast Q
 where I.entry_no= L.entry_no and I.item_code=P.item_code and P.shelf_id= Q.shelf_id 
 and P.sec_id= Q.sec_id and   L.entry_date >= ''2018-06-23'' and L.entry_date <= ''2018-06-23''  and L.valid = ''1''


) as PivotData
PIVOT
(
   SUM(unit_qty)
   FOR LocationName IN (' + @Columns + ')
) AS PivotResult
ORDER BY Shelf'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

This code is working perfectly as per my concept.

**RESULT**

[image: This is the result]

I want this report in Crystal Reports, I tried so many things, unfortunately its failed

Please am new in PIVOT table in SQL Server. Please help me to solve this Issue

Comment: So the question is how to get those results in a Crystal report? You said the pivot code works perfectly, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use raw data and let Crystal do the pivot using a CrossTab.
This would keep things simple and ensure the result set always has the same columns.